# SignalR .NET Framework WCF Server consumed by a Blazor WASM client

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, blazor, .net-4.8

Is this possible ?

I made a small demo app, and when using .NetFramework as a server, and a .NetFramework asa client everything works fine...

Then, I was lucky enough to find before even trying,that the "AspNet.SignalR" packages (used for SignalR in my WCF .NetFramework service(server)) is not compatible with "AspNetCore.SignalR" used by my Blazor WASM project...

Now, my question is, how can I get to a "middle-ground" in this situation ?
I cannot migrate the .NetFramework app to .NET unfortunately.
Is there any chance i can consume the SignalR from .NET, when having a .NET Framework (v4.7) as a SignalR server?

Comment: One solution that is quite hacky is to create another app that has both the .NET Core SignalR and .NET Framework SignalR. This will act just like middleware. You connect both of your apps to this middleware. When it receives a message from the .NET Core version, it will pass it down to the .NET Framework version and vice-versa. I do not know if there is anything better.

Comment: I am actually trying to JSInterop my way out of this.
Gonna use JS (that is compatible with ASP.NET version of SignalR), and call it with Interop from my Blazor WASM... gonna be tricky but will do the work, i assume...